# Web Scraping a Amazon

Tags: nodejs, scraping

Estoy tratando de seguir las pautas de un tutorial de web scrapping en Amazon, el cual utiliza pupeteer y cheerio.

Tengo las dependencias instaladas en node:

```
{
  "name": "scrapy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.2",
    "puppeteer": "^10.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Ahora bien, consigo exportar 'cheerio' sin problema en una constante global llamada '$', tal y como viene en el tutorial. Igualmente traté de ponerle una palabra y sigue dando el fallo, así que deduzco que no es el caracter.

Aquí tengo el código:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-WHCH710N/dp/B085RNVJ3P/';

async function configureBrowser(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    return page;
}

async function checkPrice(page){
    await page.reload();
    let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    //console.log(html);

    $('#priceblock_saleprice', html).each(function(){
        let dollarPrice = $(this).text();
        console.log(dollarPrice)
    });
}

async function monitor(){
    let page = await configureBrowser();
     await checkPrice(page);
}

monitor();
```

Y aquí pongo el log del error:

```
(node:11639) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: $ is not a function
    at checkPrice (/home/linux3/Escritorio/www/scrapy/index.js:20:5)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async monitor (/home/linux3/Escritorio/www/scrapy/index.js:28:6)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11639) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11639) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

No entiendo qué puede ser, ya que sigo el github igual excepto el scrap de la web, ya que ellos usan amazon `en` y yo `es`.

[Enlace a GitHub](https://github.com/tombaranowicz/AmazonPricesMonitoring/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: y lo probaste en amazon en? ahi tampoco funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como te [comenté](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58606180#58606180) en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de la comunidad, tu problema está en la forma en que utilizas la librería [`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) en la versión que tienes instalada (`1.0.0-rc.10`).

Tienes esto:

```
const $ = require('cheerio');
```

y más adelante haces esto:

```
 $('#priceblock_saleprice', html).each( ... )
```

Sin embargo en la [documentación](https://cheerio.js.org/) te indica que primero debes [cargar (*load*)](https://cheerio.js.org/modules.html#load) el texto `html` antes de poder usar la librería.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución sería cargar el `html` una vez obtenido, para ello tendrías que modificar tu importación de la librería de la siguiente forma:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

Luego, en el momento que obtienes el contenido `html` debes cargarlo en memoria de la siguiente forma:

```js
// dentro de 'checkPrice()'
// ...
let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
//console.log(html);
const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false);  // <- aquí se carga el html recién leído (tercer argumento false, porque se trata de un fragmento y no un documento completo)
// ahora si puedo usar $
  $('#priceblock_saleprice').each( ... );  // <- no hace falta pasar el parámetro 'html'
// ...
```

De esta forma la salida del código que muestras en tu pregunta, aplicando los cambios de esta respuesta sería:

```sh
> US$ 98.00
```

El código completo de `index.js` sería el siguiente:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-WHCH710N/dp/B085RNVJ3P/';

async function configureBrowser(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    return page;
}

async function checkPrice(page){
    await page.reload();
    let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    //console.log(html);
    const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false);
    $('#priceblock_saleprice').each(function(){
        let dollarPrice = $(this).text();
        console.log(dollarPrice)
    });
}

async function monitor(){
    let page = await configureBrowser();
     await checkPrice(page);
}

monitor();
```

Puedes ver una grabación de la implementación en: [`asciinema`](https://asciinema.org/a/425338)

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Perfecta respuesta. Muchas gracias!